# The nightly build of rustfmt does not run on another Windows PC

Tags: rust

I built the latest master branch of rustfmt on a x64 Windows 8.1 PC using Rust nightly 2015/07/18.

```
cargo build --release
```

[rustfmt](https://github.com/nrc/rustfmt) needs a nightly version of Rust.

And I copied the rustfmt.exe to another x64 PC, but it can not run and showed some dlls are missing.

They are std-74fa456f.dll, log-74fa456f.dll, rustc-74fa456f.dll, and syntax-74fa456f.dll.

Rust stable 1.1.0 is installed on the second PC.

Comment: Rust does not have a stable ABI. Having a different version of Rust installed is completely meaningless; they use different versions of all their libraries. You haven’t gone and specified *what* DLLs are missing, nor what efforts you made to *provide* those DLLs.

Comment: Did you compile with the same version of Rust on both machines? You should [edit] your question to include the version of Rust on both machines - "stable" could mean either the 1.0 or 1.1 release by now. In the future, it will include even more!

Answer (score 1):

You need to copy all the dlls from where Rust is installed on the first PC. For example, `C:\Rust`, And copy all the required dlls for rustfmt.exe in `C:\Rust\bin` to the second PC on the same folder as rustfmt.exe.